# Xpath accessing the value of an attribute within an XML tag

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml

I'm attempting to extract the date saved in the `<PersonDetails>` tag for some XML I am working with, example:

```
    <Record>
        <PersonDetails RecordDate="2017-03-31T00:00:00">
                <FirstName>Joe</FirstName>
                <Surname>Blogs</Surname>
                <Status>Active</Status>
        </PersonDetails>
    </Record>
```

Currently I have been trying the following:

```
if (isset($XML->Record->xpath("//PersonDetails[@RecordDate]")[0])) {

$theDate = $XML->Record->xpath("//PersonDetails[@RecordDate]")[0])->textContent;

} else {

$theDate = "no date";

}
```

My intention is to have `$theDate = 2017-03-31T00:00:00`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A valid XPath expression for selecting attribute node should look like below:

```
$theDate = $XML->xpath("//Record/PersonDetails/@RecordDate")[0];

echo $theDate;   // 2017-03-31T00:00:00
```

Comment: Thank you Roman, I got this to work thanks to you. Just out of interest, I kept using this 'semi' xpath: `$XML->Record->xpath("//PersonDetails[@RecordDate]")[0])` just changing it to: `$XML->Record->xpath("//PersonDetails/@RecordDate")[0])` and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing SimpleXML and DOM here. Additionally the expression fetches a `PersonDetails` element that has a `RecordDate` attribute. `[]` are conditions.

### SimpleXML

So to fetch attribute node you need to use `//PersonDetails/@RecordDate`. In SimpleXML this will create a SimpleXMLElement for a non existing element node that will return the attribute value if cast to a string. SimpleXMLElement::xpath() will always return an array so you need to cast the first element of that array into a string.

```
$theDate = (string)$XML->xpath("//PersonDetails/@RecordDate")[0];
```

### DOM

`$textContent` is a property of DOM nodes. It contains the text content of all descendant nodes. But you don't need it in this case. If you use `DOMXpath::evaluate()`, the Xpath expression can return the string value directly.

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml($xmlString);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

$theDate = $xpath->evaluate('string(//PersonDetails/@RecordDate)');
```

The string typecast is moved into the Xpath expression.